# How do I output the previous logged in IP's during an SSH login to my ubuntu server?

Tags: ssh, login, startup, startup-scripts

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and everytime I log in, I would like to see the previous IP addresses that logged in to my server. How would I go about doing this? I have fail2ban installed already.

Comment: in sshd_config "     PrintLastLog
             Specifies whether sshd should print the date and time of the last user login when a user logs in interactively.  The default is “yes”.
"

Comment: where is that file ?

Comment: /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: can you print the last 10 IP's that logged in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shell initialization script (e.g., `~/.bash_profile`) add `last --ip --limit 10`

Comment: The arguments you suggest for `last` do not exist. However using `limit` without arguments usually provides the information asked for (after a rotation, one would need to check one earlier logfile as well.)

Comment: Yeah, Precise uses a last from sysvinit-utils, version 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1. The one I use in gentoo: last from util-linux 2.24.2

Answer (score 0):

You should see a "Last login from IP" message everytime you login.

You could also use the command "history" to view a log of commands that have been used.

If you want to check the current logged in users, use the command "w"